# prove (by grammar or closures) that the prefix language is context free

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have a language $L$, which is context-free, and I have $Pref(L)$, which is the language of all the prefixes of the words in $L$.

I need to prove that $pref(L)$ is context free only with closures or grammar.

I can use some help please...thanks in advance

P.S. I'm aware of the fact that there is a question about this language already, but I didn't manage to understand anything of it, and I don't have the permission to comment on the other question. Sorry in advance for duplicating.

Comment: Note, that sort of questions would be welcome in [cs](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). Not that there's anything wrong with posting it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest that you take your grammar in Chomsky Normal Form and for every production $A \to BC$ add productions $A_\varepsilon \to BC_\varepsilon$  and  $A_\varepsilon \to B_\varepsilon$. Also, for every $A \to a$ add the two rules $A_\varepsilon \to a$ and $A_\varepsilon \to \varepsilon$. Finally change the starting symbol to $S_\varepsilon$ and add $S_\varepsilon \to \varepsilon$. Now any derivation tree will have some $X_\varepsilon$ as the rightmost symbol and it will thus be possible to terminate it at any step.

Comment: Thank you so much! One thing only - is S'(you called it S epsilon) points to the original S? if not, where to then?

Comment: If $S \to XY$ then $S_\varepsilon \to XY_\varepsilon$ as for any other $\varepsilon$ production I suggested to introduce. I'm not sure if it is okay to change the starting symbol though (as $S$ is traditional). If not, some renaming can solve that...

Comment: Yuu also need $A_{\varepsilon}\to B_{\varepsilon}$, I think.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes, if $A \to B$ is in your definition of the normal form. It seems productions of that kind are often omitted. They are easy to replace, after all.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: No, I mean if $A\to BC$ is in the original grammar, then you need $A_{\varepsilon}\to B_{\varepsilon}$ in order for $A_{\varepsilon}$ to generate all prefixes of what $A$ generates.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I see you are right. I'll fix the answer...

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Hi , you added new variables to keep it in Chomsky Normal Form? if we don't care if the new CFG will be in HNF or not, we could just add for all rules of the form $A\to BC$ the rule $A\to B$. right? (of course under the assumption that we start with a HNF CFG)

Comment: @sha no,you need the extra variables. For example, if the grammar is $S \to XX, X \to AB, A \to a, B \to b$ (so that $L = \{abab\}$), and then you add $X \to A$, then new grammar will also produce the word $aa$ which is not a prefix of $abab$.

Comment: Do you mean that with every $X_{\varepsilon}$ comes a rule of the form $X_{\varepsilon} \to \varepsilon$? Otherwise your statement about termination at any time does not make sense to me...

Comment: @StefanH no, you cut off the end of a string by choosing the rule $A_\varepsilon \to B_\varepsilon$ instead of $A_\varepsilon \to BC_\varepsilon$. While some of the cutting could be done using $X \to \varepsilon$ rules, it's neither necessary nor sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

Karolis has given a nice construction involving grammars, I will add the alternative options given in your question, closure properties.

Let $\Sigma$ be the alphabet for your language. We take a copy $\bar\Sigma = \{ \bar a \mid a\in \Sigma\}$. Let $h : (\Sigma\cup\bar\Sigma)^* \to \Sigma^*$ be the morphism that removes bars: $h(a) = a$, $h(\bar a)=a$ for all $a\in\Sigma$. Let $g : (\Sigma\cup\bar\Sigma)^* \to \Sigma^*$ be the morphism that deletes barred letters: $g(a) = a$, $g(\bar a)=\varepsilon$ for all $a\in\Sigma$.

Then for $u\in\Sigma^*$, $h^{-1}(u)$ is the set of strings that result from $u$ by "barring" an arbitrary subset of letters in the string. In that we we select them for deletion. In the prefix operation we cannot delete arbitrary letters, by only suffixes. Thus we restrict the selection by intersection with a proper regular language:
$pref(L) =  g( h^{-1}(L) \cap \Sigma^*\bar\Sigma^* )$.

Same approach for instance: language of subwords $g( h^{-1}(L) \cap \bar\Sigma^*\Sigma^*\bar\Sigma^* )$, delete every even letter in the string $g( h^{-1}(L) \cap ( (\Sigma\bar\Sigma)^* \cup (\Sigma\bar\Sigma)^*\Sigma ) )$.

Formally, any family of languages closed under morphisms, inverse morphisms, and intersection with regular languages is closed under prefix. Such a family is called *cone* or *full trio*. So also valid for regular languages and recursively enumerable languages.